# csv.DictReader exception at end of file

Tags: python, csv

I am using the following code as a proof-of concept for parsing the [FCC License View](http://www.fcc.gov/developer/license-view-api) sample [data set](http://data.fcc.gov/download/license-view/fcc-license-view-data-sample.csv):

```
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_file = open('fcc-license-view-data-sample.csv', 'rb')
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_file.read(1024))
    csv_file.seek(0)
    data = csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect=dialect)
    for item in data:
        print item
```

After the module has printed all of the data, an exception is thrown:

> ```
> File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 104, in next
> row = self.reader.next()
> ```
>
> _csv.Error: newline inside string

Why does this exception occur? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That CSV file sample seems to be cut off mid-line. The very end is

```
 "2600 TOWER OAKS BOULEVARD","ROCKVILLE","MD","2085
```

Note the unclosed quotes.

Just don't process the last line if you want to operate on just the sample. I think this should work:

```
def all_but_last_line(file):
    last = next(file)
    for line in file:
        yield last

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('fcc-license-view-data-sample.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_file.read(1024))
        csv_file.seek(0)
        data = csv.DictReader(all_but_last_line(csv_file), dialect=dialect)
        for item in data:
            print item
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I get for viewing the CSV file in LibreOffice instead of a plain editor :)

Answer (score 0):

I post , sure very late an answer to this, but because i had the same problem , there is a trick

Maybe that's because you scan a directory for csv file and digest them in python.

My trick to not take file during there are uploading :

use [inotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) system to inspect for file who are closed.

Or for a cron like process create a "intermediate room": ftp directory > process directory and use a bash trick :

```
source=directorySource
destination=directoryDestination
cd $source
for file in `find $source  -mtime +1  -print `
do 
    mv $file $destination$file
done
```