# Last element of csv reader in Python

Tags: python, iterator

How do you detect the last row in a csv file?  It is an iterator but I cannot find a way to detect the last row:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

for idx, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
    # How to detect last row?
```

Comment: Why do you need to know the last row? What are you doing with it that is so special?

Comment: Your silver bullet might be `.next()` or `.line_number`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac i confirm thats `.next()`. @Dane check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11479202/2029818

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I am converting csv to json. Last row should now have the trailing coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want custom behavior, write a custom iterater.  Adapting the second example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7976272/208880):

```
Empty = object()

class BooleanIterator(object):
    """
    True/False tests:  True means there are items still remaining to be used
    """
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self._iter = iter(iterator)
        self._get_next_value()
    def __next__(self):
        value = self._next_value
        self._get_next_value()
        if value is not Empty:
            return value
        raise StopIteration
    next = __next__                     # python 2.x
    def __bool__(self):
        return self._next_value is not Empty
    __nonzero__ = __bool__              # python 2.x
    def _get_next_value(self):
        self._next_value = next(self._iter, Empty)
```

In your code:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')

reader = BooleanIterator(csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames))

for idx, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
    if reader:
        # not the last row
        # process normally
    else:
        # this is the last row!
```

For more examples of iterators see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542261/208880).

Answer (score 2):

You can always just convert to a list and take the last element of the list

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

all_lines = list(reader)
last_line = all_lines[-1]
```

Comment: This may cause problems if the file is very large as it will require reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, its up to the user to define which solution best fits the needs of the situation

Answer (score 2):

As stated, using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) is probably the best bet

```
csvfile     = open('file.csv', 'r')

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

mycsv = enumerate(reader, start=1)
idx, row = mycsv.next()
while row:
    try:
       next_set = mycsv.next()
       pass # process set of (idx, row) here
       idx, row = next_set
    except StopIteration:
       pass # process last row here
       idx, row = None # make sure to unset to kill the loop
```